# Get byte size of long and convert, GAS

Tags: assembly

I have a long such as:

> > var: .long 0

In my program, I am adding values to var which works fine. My question is, how would I go about calculating the byte size of the long so that I can convert it to MB.

Currently, when I print out the long in hex, I get:

> > 04F3AC20

So I am trying to get the byte size of that in MB.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear whether you want the number converted to MB, or whether you want to know how many bytes long your storage location is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `long` is four bytes long, based on the size of the number you show. To be sure, I would set it to `-1`, then print as hex. I expect the answer will be `FFFFFFFF` which will confirm it is four bytes (each hex nibble / letter is four bits, representing the numbers 0 - 15, and eight bits is one byte).

If instead your question is "what is `0x04F3AC20` in MB", you can divide the number by 2^20 (right shift by 20) to get the answer. In this case

```
0x04F3AD20 >> 20
0x0000004F
```

(since each nibble is four bits, we shift by 5 "digits") and the answer is `4F` MB, or `64 + 15 = 79 MB`

Comment: Okay, so I was able to shift correctly and output 4F. Now how would I go about taking the word "004F" stored in a register and converting it to the final integer. I am guessing loop through each bit and add 30 to it for the ascii char?

Comment: The number `4F` is just the hex representation of `79`. Are you asking how to convert to an actual ASCII string? Don't you have a print command that allows you to do that? If you don't, then you should take the number modulo 10, and add the ASCII value of `'0'` - that is your last digit. Divide by ten, and repeat for the next digit (to the left) until the number is zero. Make sense?

Comment: Unless you're a disk drive manufacturer, in which case you want to divide by 1e6 instead of shifting by 20 bits...

Comment: @twalberg - you are right. But I'm an old guy- to me a MB is 2^20, not 1,000,000 . I guess I won't be marketing disk drives for a living...